# Tengo problema con la función que suma los totales en Python

Tags: python

estoy empezando a aprender programación y lo estoy tratando de hacer con Python, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto personal para calcular el salario y a su vez almacenar la información en una pequeña base de datos en sqlite, sin embargo, estoy teniendo problemas con la función "datos" que hace la suma e intento que devuelva algunos valores totales, si alguien puede orientarme que estoy haciendo mal, le agradezco.

Todo funciona bien, se muestra el programa con todos los widgets, hace los primeros cálculos y los muestra en cada etiqueta, guarda bien la información en la base de datos, pero no suma los valores para mostrarlos en las etiquetas de los valores totales.

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from baseDatos import *

ANCHO = 900
ALTO = 1000
POSX = 400
POSY = 50
anchoAlto = str(ANCHO) + "x" + str(ALTO)
posicionX = "+" + str( POSX)
posicionY = "+" + str(POSY)
colorVentana = "gray"
colorFondo = "gray"
colorTexto = "black"
VALOR_HORA_NORMAL = 13.00
VALOR_HORA_EXTRA = 19.50

def mostrarMensaje(titulo, mensaje):
    messagebox.showinfo(titulo, mensaje)

def limpiarDatos():
    hora_normal.set(" ")
    hora_extra.set(" ")
    messageLabel_9_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_10_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_11_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_12_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_13_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_14_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_15_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_16_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_17_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_18_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_19_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_20_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_21_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    messageLabel_22_1.configure(text='------------- ')
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)

def calcular():
    cantidadHN = hora_normal.get()
    cantidadHE = hora_extra.get()
    totalHsemana = cantidadHN + cantidadHE
    messageLabel_9_1.configure(text = round (totalHsemana, 2))
    valorHN = (VALOR_HORA_NORMAL * cantidadHN)
    messageLabel_10_1.configure(text = valorHN)
    valorHE = (VALOR_HORA_EXTRA * cantidadHE)
    messageLabel_11_1.configure(text = round (valorHE, 2))
    salario_no_descuentos = valorHN + valorHE
    seguridad_social =salario_no_descuentos * 0.062
    medicare = salario_no_descuentos * 0.0145
    valorSemana = salario_no_descuentos - (seguridad_social + medicare)
    messageLabel_12_1.configure(text =round(valorSemana, 2))
    diezmoSemana = salario_no_descuentos * 0.10
    messageLabel_18_1.configure(text= round(diezmoSemana, 2))
    dctoSemana = (seguridad_social + medicare)
    messageLabel_19_1.configure(text= round(dctoSemana, 2))
    totalHN = 0 # En esta variable se va a ir sumando el total de la cantidad de horas normales que se vayan ingresando en el programa
    totalHN =+ cantidadHN
    messageLabel_13_1.configure(text = round(totalHN, 2))
    totalHE = 0 # En esta variable se va a ir sumando el total de la cantidad de horas extras que se vayan ingresando en el programa
    totalHE =+ cantidadHE
    messageLabel_14_1.configure(text = round(totalHE, 2))
    totalHanio = totalHN + totalHE # En esta variable se va a guardar la totalidad de horas laboradas
    messageLabel_15_1.configure(text = round(totalHanio, 2))
    valorTotalHN = 0
    valorTotalHN =+ valorHN
    messageLabel_16_1.configure(text = round(valorTotalHN, 2))
    valorTotalHE = 0
    valorTotalHE =+ valorHE
    messageLabel_17_1.configure(text = round(valorTotalHE, 2))
    dctoTotal = 0 # En esta variable se almacena la suma de los descuentos de cada semana
    dctoTotal =+ dctoSemana
    messageLabel_20_1.configure(text = round(dctoTotal, 2))
    diezmoTotal = 0 # En esta variable se almacena la suma de los diezmos de cada semana
    diezmoTotal =+ diezmoSemana
    messageLabel_21_1.configure(text = round(diezmoTotal, 2))
    valorTotalAnio = 0 # En esta variable se almacena la sumatoria de los salarios semanales
    valorTotalAnio =+ valorSemana
    messageLabel_22_1.configure(text = round(valorTotalAnio, 2))
    return cantidadHN, cantidadHE, totalHsemana, round(valorSemana, 2), totalHN, totalHE, totalHanio, round(diezmoSemana, 2), round(diezmoTotal, 2), round(dctoSemana, 2), round(dctoTotal, 2), round(valorTotalAnio, 2)

def datos():
    totalHN_base = 0
    totalHE_base = 0
    totalHanio_base = 0
    dctoTotal_base = 0
    diezmoTotal_base = 0
    valorTotalAnio_base = 0
    cantidadHN, cantidadHE, totalHsemana, valorSemana, totalHN, totalHE, totalHanio, diezmoSemana, diezmoTotal, dctoSemana, dctoTotal, valorTotalAnio = calcular()
    totalHN_base += totalHN
    totalHE_base += totalHE
    totalHanio_base += totalHanio
    dctoTotal_base += dctoTotal
    diezmoTotal_base += diezmoTotal
    valorTotalAnio_base += valorTotalAnio
    print(cantidadHN, cantidadHE, totalHsemana, valorSemana, totalHN, totalHE, totalHanio, diezmoSemana, diezmoTotal, dctoSemana, dctoTotal, valorTotalAnio)
    return cantidadHN, cantidadHE, totalHsemana, valorSemana, totalHN_base, totalHE_base, totalHanio_base, diezmoSemana, diezmoTotal_base, dctoSemana, dctoTotal_base, valorTotalAnio_base

def guardar():
    calcular() #Realiza las operaciones coorespondientes para mostrar los resultados en cada una de las etiquetas de la interfaz, RETORNA los valores que resultan de cada ejecución
    datos() # Recibe los valores que se generan en la función calcular y va sumando los valores en las variables de los totales, RETORNA, los valores ya sumados listos para la BASE DE DATOS
    crearTabla()
    if(hora_normal.get() == 0 and hora_extra.get()== 0):
        mostrarMensaje("Error", "Debes ingresar las horas laboradas ")
    else:
        mostrarMensaje("Guardar", "Información Guardada")
        insertar(datos())
        mostrar()

def mostrar():
    listado = consultar()
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)
    textoBase.insert(INSERT, "Semana\tHoraN\tHoraE\tHSem\tValorS\tTotHN\tTotHE\tTotHAño\tDiezmoS\tDiezmoT\tDctoSem\tDctoTot\tValorTotalAño\n")
    for elemento in listado:
        id = elemento[0]
        horasNormales = elemento[1]
        horasExtras = elemento[2]
        horasSemana = elemento[3]
        valorSemana = elemento[4]
        totalHN = elemento[5]
        totalHE = elemento[6]
        totalHAnio = elemento[7]
        diezmoSemana = elemento[8]
        diezmoTotal = elemento[9]
        dctoSemana = elemento[10]
        dctoTotal = elemento[11]
        valorTotalAnio = elemento[12]
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, id)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, horasNormales)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, horasExtras)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, horasSemana)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, valorSemana)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, totalHN)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, totalHE)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, totalHAnio)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, diezmoSemana)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, diezmoTotal)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, dctoSemana)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, dctoTotal)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t")
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, valorTotalAnio)
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\n")

ventana = Tk()
ventana.config(bg= colorVentana)
ventana.geometry(anchoAlto +posicionX + posicionY)
ventana. title("Calcula Sueldos")
# Etiquetas
messageLabel_2 = Label(ventana, text ='"GOYA"', font=("Arial", 25)).place(x = 380, y = 10)
messageLabel_3 = Label(ventana, text ='Alexander Carrero', width=15, height=2).grid(row = 4, column=0, padx=17, pady=20)
messageLabel_7 = Label(ventana, text ='Cantidad H. N', width=15).grid(row = 8, column=0, padx=17, pady=10)
hora_normal = DoubleVar()
hora_normal_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_normal, width=11).grid(row = 8, column = 1)
messageLabel_8 = Label(ventana, text ='Cantidad H. E', width=15).grid(row = 8, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
hora_extra = DoubleVar()
hora_extra_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_extra, width=11).grid(row = 8, column = 3)
messageLabel_9 = Label(ventana, text ='Total H. Semana', width=15).grid(row = 8, column=4, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_9_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_9_1.grid(row = 8, column=5)
messageLabel_10 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor H. N', width=15).grid(row = 10, column=0, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_10_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_10_1.grid(row = 10, column=1)
messageLabel_11 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor H. E', width=15).grid(row = 10, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_11_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_11_1.grid(row = 10, column=3)
messageLabel_12 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor Semana', width=15).grid(row = 10, column=4, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_12_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_12_1.grid(row = 10, column=5)
messageLabel_13 = Label(ventana, text ='Total H. N', width=15).grid(row = 12, column=0, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_13_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_13_1.grid(row = 12, column=1)
messageLabel_14 = Label(ventana, text ='Total H. E', width=15).grid(row = 12, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_14_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_14_1.grid(row = 12, column=3)
messageLabel_15 = Label(ventana, text ='Total H. Año', width=15).grid(row = 12, column=4, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_15_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_15_1.grid(row = 12, column=5)
messageLabel_16 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor Total H. N', width=15).grid(row = 14, column=0, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_16_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_16_1.grid(row = 14, column=1)
messageLabel_17 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor Total H. E', width=15).grid(row = 14, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_17_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_17_1.grid(row = 14, column=3)
messageLabel_18 = Label(ventana, text ='Diezmo Semana', width=15).grid(row = 14, column=4, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_18_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_18_1.grid(row = 14, column=5)
messageLabel_19 = Label(ventana, text ='Dcto Semana', width=15).grid(row = 16, column=0, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_19_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_19_1.grid(row = 16, column=1)
messageLabel_20 = Label(ventana, text ='Total Dcto', width=15).grid(row = 16, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_20_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_20_1.grid(row = 16, column=3)
messageLabel_21 = Label(ventana, text ='Diezmo Total', width=15).grid(row = 16, column=4, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_21_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_21_1.grid(row = 16, column=5)
messageLabel_22 = Label(ventana, text ='Valor Total Año', width=15).grid(row = 18, column=2, padx=17, pady=10)
messageLabel_22_1 = Label(ventana, text ='------------- ', width=11)
messageLabel_22_1.grid(row = 18, column=3)

#Widgets
boton_calcular = Button(ventana, text= "Calcular Info", font=("Comic Sans", 13),  fg= "Blue", command = guardar, width= 15, height=2).place(x=160, y=350)
boton_salir = Button(ventana, text= "Limpiar Pantalla", font=("Comic Sans", 13),   fg= "Blue", command = limpiarDatos, width= 15, height=2).place(x=360, y=350)
boton_salir = Button(ventana, text= "Mostrar Info", font=("Comic Sans", 13),   fg= "Blue", command = mostrar, width= 15, height=2).place(x=560, y=350)
etiquetaBase = Label(ventana, text='"Histórico" ', font=("Arial", 25)).place(x = 380, y = 420)
textoBase = Text(ventana)
textoBase.config(width=120, height=35)
textoBase.place(x = 30, y = 470,)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No acabo de entender del todo la funcionalidad de tu código, en particular en lo que respecta a los totales porque veo que intentas calcular algunos de esos totales en la función `calcular()` (y estaba mal por lo que luego explicaré), pero otros los calculas en la función `datos()` y no entiendo si se trata de otros totales diferentes, o de los mismos pero calculados otra vez.

### Mejora inicial antes de abordar el problema

Al margen de ese problema con los totales tu código tenía un problema importante (típico cuando se empieza) y es la definición de montones de variables muy similares que solo cambian un poco al final en el nombre para cada una de las labels, y código **muy repetitivo** a base de copiar, pegar y modificar para crear cada una de esas labels en una cierta posición y con un cierto texto.

Esto suele ser un síntoma de que un bucle resolvería el problema de forma mucho más compacta y menos proclive a errores, junto con una estructura de datos para guardar todas esas variables.

En este caso creo que la estructura más adecuada podría ser un diccionario en el que cada clave sea el "nombre" de la label correspondiente donde se mostrará un resultado. Fíjate que las labels que contienen el mero nombre, como por ejemplo "Valor H.N" no necesitamos guardarlas en variables, pues no vamos a acceder a ellas nunca. Sólo las labels que se usarán para mostrar resultados necesitan ser guardadas (son las que en tu código original tenían nombres terminados en `_1`).

Así pues, todo el código que tenías repetitivo para crear esas labels se puede reducir a lo siguiente, con ayuda de listas, diccionarios y un bucle. Primero creo una lista con los textos que saldrán en la ventana, organizados ya en filas según el orden en que los quieres ver:

```
layout = [["Cantidad H.N",    "Cantidad H.E",    "Total H. Semana"],
          ["Valor H.N",       "Valor H.E",       "Valor Semana"],
          ["Total H.N",       "Total H.E",       "Total Año"],
          ["Valor Total H.N", "Valor Total H.E", "Diezmo Semana"],
          ["Dcto Semana",     "Total Dcto",      "Diezmo Total"],
          ["Valor Total Año"]]
```

Seguidamente mediante un bucle recorro las filas de esa lista, y en cada iteración recorro las columnas para sacar cada texto. En base a ese texto creo la label correspondiente, en la fila y columna que le toque (que voy actualizando en otras dos variables).

Los casos en los que el texto sea `"Cantidad H.N"` y `"Cantidad H.E"` se tratan de forma diferente a todos los demás, porque en éstos se va a definir una `Entry` y no irán al diccionario de labels. Las demás se crean todas de la misma forma, evitando el código repetitivo.

```
messageLabel = {}
row = 8
column = 0
for fila in layout:
    column = 0
    for txt in fila:
        if txt == "Cantidad H.N":
            Label(ventana, text=txt, width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            hora_normal = DoubleVar()
            hora_normal_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_normal, width=11).grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        elif txt == "Cantidad H.E":
            Label(ventana, text ='Cantidad H. E', width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            hora_extra = DoubleVar()
            hora_extra_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_extra, width=11).grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        else:
            if txt == "Valor Total Año":
                column = 2  # Esta no va en la columna que le tocaría

            # Y ahora este es el código común para crear todos los demás casos
            Label(ventana, text=txt, width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            messageLabel[txt] = Label(ventana, text='------------- ', width=11)
            messageLabel[txt].grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        column += 2
    row +=2
```

Este código va metiendo en el diccionario `messageLabel` los objetos que luego permitirán acceder a esas labels para cambiar su contenido. Por ejemplo, tendrás en el diccionario `messageLabel["Valor H.N"]` de donde podrás sacar la label para modificarla.

Eso permite simplificar enormemente la función que limpia la pantalla, mediante otro bucle para rellenar con "----" cada una de las labels.

```
def limpiarDatos():
    hora_normal.set(" ")
    hora_extra.set(" ")
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)
    for label in messageLabel.values():
        label.configure(text='------------- ')
```

### Otro diccionario, ahora para datos

El diccionario para guardar las labels ha permitido simplificar mucho el código. Usemos otro diccionario para cada una de las variables que vas computando en la función `calcular`. La ventaja de usar un diccionario en este caso es que podemos usar como claves del diccionario las mismas cadenas que usamos para definir las labels. De este modo podremos después escribir una función muy simple que rellene cada label con el dato sacado del diccionario, porque ambos usarían la misma clave.

Además, si ese diccionario es una variable global, nos servirá para guardar en el los totales de modo que no se "olviden" entre las diferentes invocaciones a `calcular()`. Este era el **fallo** que tenías, que volvías a poner esos totales a 0 dentro de `calcular()` y por tanto no se podía "recordar" su valor previo.

El diccionario que propongo sería así:

```
data = {
    "Cantidad H.N": 0,    "Cantidad H.E": 0, "Total H. Semana": 0,
    "Valor H.N": 0,       "Valor H.E": 0,    "Valor Semana": 0,
    "Diezmo Semana": 0,   "Dcto Semana": 0,  "Total H.N": 0,
    "Total H.E": 0,       "Total Año": 0,    "Valor Total H.N": 0,
    "Valor Total H.E": 0, "Total Dcto": 0,   "Diezmo Total": 0,
    "Valor Total Año": 0
}
```

En realidad podemos ser más listos. Ya que las claves de este diccionario son iguales a las claves del diccionario de etiquetas (tienen que serlo, debido a cómo lo usaremos luego), podemos crear este diccionario a partir de la información que hay en la lista `layout` para evitar tener que volver a teclear esos nombres evitando así la posibilidad de equivocarse.

Usando esta idea, `data` se inicializaría así:

```
data = { nombre: 0 for fila in layout for nombre in fila }
```

Ahora, gracias a que las claves son las mismas que en el diccionario `messageLabel`, podemos escribir también una función para actualizar la interfaz con los datos que haya en `data`, usando un bucle muy sencillo:

```
def mostrarDatos(data):
    """Usa los valores del diccionario data para mostrarlos en las labels
    de la interfaz de usuario. Usa las claves del diccionario para encontrar
    la label correspondiente"""
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k in messageLabel:
            messageLabel[k].configure(text=round(v, 2))
```

Eso nos permitirá también simplificar mucho la función `calcular()` que tal como la tenías mezclaba código que era para realizar los cálculos con código que era para mostrar los resultados. Ahora podemos separar más claramente y dedicarnos tan solo a los cálculos y al final del todo llamar a la función `mostrarDatos()` para que los muestre.

Por tanto quedará así:

```
def calcular():
    data["Cantidad H.N"] = hora_normal.get()
    data["Cantidad H.E"] = hora_extra.get()
    data["Total H. Semana"] = data["Cantidad H.N"] + data["Cantidad H.E"]
    data["Valor H.N"] = (VALOR_HORA_NORMAL * data["Cantidad H.N"])
    data["Valor H.E"] = (VALOR_HORA_EXTRA * data["Cantidad H.E"])
    salario_no_descuentos = data["Valor H.N"]  + data["Valor H.E"]
    seguridad_social =salario_no_descuentos * 0.062
    medicare = salario_no_descuentos * 0.0145
    data["Valor Semana"]  = salario_no_descuentos - (seguridad_social + medicare)
    data["Diezmo Semana"] = salario_no_descuentos * 0.10
    data["Dcto Semana"] = (seguridad_social + medicare)
    data["Total H.N"] += data["Cantidad H.N"]
    data["Total H.E"] += data["Cantidad H.E"]
    data["Total Año"] = data["Total H.N"] + data["Total H.E"]
    data["Valor Total H.N"] += data["Valor H.N"]
    data["Valor Total H.E"] += data["Valor H.E"]
    data["Total Dcto"] += data["Dcto Semana"]
    data["Diezmo Total"] += data["Diezmo Semana"]
    data["Valor Total Año"] += data["Valor Semana"]
    mostrarDatos(data)
```

Como ves, en lugar de usar variables para los cálculos uso las claves del diccionario, al menos en las que después se van a mostrar en la interfaz. Otras variables intermedias sólo para uso interno (como `salario_no_descuentos`) no necesitan estar en el diccionario.

Ya que esta función ya va computando los totales y los va guardando en el diccionario `data`, no necesitas ya la otra función que tenías `datos()`, que además también estaba mal porque volvía a llamar a `calcular()` dentro (por lo que los totales volverían a crecer).

La función `guardar()` también era incorrecta porque estaba así:

```
def guardar():
    calcular() #Realiza las operaciones coorespondientes para mostrar los resultados en cada una de las etiquetas de la interfaz, RETORNA los valores que resultan de cada ejecución
    datos() # Recibe los valores que se generan en la función calcular y va sumando los valores en las variables de los totales, RETORNA, los valores ya sumados listos para la BASE DE DATOS
    crearTabla()
    if(hora_normal.get() == 0 and hora_extra.get()== 0):
        mostrarMensaje("Error", "Debes ingresar las horas laboradas ")
    else:
        mostrarMensaje("Guardar", "Información Guardada")
        insertar(datos())
        mostrar()
```

Aquí hay varios errores. Comienzas llamando a `calcular()`, pero seguidamente llamabas a `datos()` la cual internamente llamaba otra vez a `calcular()`. Después miras si se han introducido horas (¿no deberías haber mirado esto antes de calcular nada?) y si se han introducido llamas a `insertar()`, pasándole como parámetro `datos()`, con lo que se volvía a ejecutar datos(), y ésta internamente volvía a llamar a `calcular()`. De modo que acababas llamando a `calcular()` tres veces! No solo esto era innecesario sino que además, ahora que calcula bien los totales, estos totales saldrían triplicados.

La nueva función `guardar()` que evite estos problemas llamará a `calcular()` una sola vez. No necesita llamar a `datos()` porque los datos ya están en el diccionario global `data`. Para facilitar su extracción de ese diccionario de cara a enviarlos a la base de datos programaré una pequeña función que saca del diccionario los valores que le pidas:

```
def extraer_valores_data(variables):
    """Del diccionario global data saca solo las variables que se le indiquen
    en la lista que recibe como parámetro"""
    return (round(data[k],2) for k in variables)
```

Y gracias a esa función, `guardar()` quedará así:

```
def guardar():
    """Si se han introducido horas, hace los cálculos, extrae los resultados
    los guarda en la base de datos, y los muestra en la ventana de texto inferior"""

    crearTabla()  # No sé qué hace esta función, yo la he implementado vacía (no hace nada)

    if(hora_normal.get() == 0 and hora_extra.get()== 0):
        mostrarMensaje("Error", "Debes ingresar las horas laboradas ")
    else:
        calcular()
        variables_a_guardar = ["Cantidad H.N", "Cantidad H.E", "Total H. Semana", "Valor Semana",
                              "Total H.N", "Total H.E", "Total Año", "Diezmo Semana", "Diezmo Total",
                              "Dcto Semana", "Total Dcto", "Valor Total Año"]
        datos_a_guardar = extraer_valores_data(variables_a_guardar)
        insertar(datos_a_guardar)
        mostrarMensaje("Guardar", "Información Guardada")
        mostrar()
```

La función `mostrar()` también se puede simplificar muchísimo mediante un bucle y el uso de la función `.join()` para crear la cadena de texto:

```
def mostrar():
    listado = consultar()
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)
    textoBase.insert(INSERT, "Semana\tHoraN\tHoraE\tHSem\tValorS\tTotHN\tTotHE\tTotHAño\tDiezmoS\tDiezmoT\tDctoSem\tDctoTot\tValorTotalAño\n")
    for elemento in listado:
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t".join(str(dato) for dato in elemento) + "\n")
    return
```

### Resultado final

Para que lo tengas todo junto, el código completo sería entonces:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from basedatos import *

ANCHO = 900
ALTO = 1000
POSX = 400
POSY = 50
anchoAlto = str(ANCHO) + "x" + str(ALTO)
posicionX = "+" + str( POSX)
posicionY = "+" + str(POSY)
colorVentana = "gray"
colorFondo = "gray"
colorTexto = "black"
VALOR_HORA_NORMAL = 13.00
VALOR_HORA_EXTRA = 19.50

layout = [["Cantidad H.N",    "Cantidad H.E",    "Total H. Semana"],
          ["Valor H.N",       "Valor H.E",       "Valor Semana"],
          ["Total H.N",       "Total H.E",       "Total Año"],
          ["Valor Total H.N", "Valor Total H.E", "Diezmo Semana"],
          ["Dcto Semana",     "Total Dcto",      "Diezmo Total"],
          ["Valor Total Año"]]

data = { nombre: 0 for fila in layout for nombre in fila }

def mostrarMensaje(titulo, mensaje):
    messagebox.showinfo(titulo, mensaje)

def limpiarDatos():
    hora_normal.set(" ")
    hora_extra.set(" ")
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)
    for label in messageLabel.values():
        label.configure(text='------------- ')

def mostrarDatos(data):
    """Usa los valores del diccionario data para mostrarlos en las labels
    de la interfaz de usuario. Usa las claves del diccionario para encontrar
    la label correspondiente"""
    for clave, valor in data.items():
        if clave in messageLabel:
            messageLabel[clave].configure(text=round(valor, 2))

def calcular():
    """Calcula una serie de datos que guarda en el diccionario data
    y al final lo muestra en la interfaz gráfica"""

    data["Cantidad H.N"] = hora_normal.get()
    data["Cantidad H.E"] = hora_extra.get()
    data["Total H. Semana"] = data["Cantidad H.N"] + data["Cantidad H.E"]
    data["Valor H.N"] = (VALOR_HORA_NORMAL * data["Cantidad H.N"])
    data["Valor H.E"] = (VALOR_HORA_EXTRA * data["Cantidad H.E"])
    salario_no_descuentos = data["Valor H.N"]  + data["Valor H.E"]
    seguridad_social =salario_no_descuentos * 0.062
    medicare = salario_no_descuentos * 0.0145
    data["Valor Semana"]  = salario_no_descuentos - (seguridad_social + medicare)
    data["Diezmo Semana"] = salario_no_descuentos * 0.10
    data["Dcto Semana"] = (seguridad_social + medicare)
    data["Total H.N"] += data["Cantidad H.N"]
    data["Total H.E"] += data["Cantidad H.E"]
    data["Total Año"] = data["Total H.N"] + data["Total H.E"]
    data["Valor Total H.N"] += data["Valor H.N"]
    data["Valor Total H.E"] += data["Valor H.E"]
    data["Total Dcto"] += data["Dcto Semana"]
    data["Diezmo Total"] += data["Diezmo Semana"]
    data["Valor Total Año"] += data["Valor Semana"]
    mostrarDatos(data)

def extraer_valores_data(variables):
    """Del diccionario global data saca solo las variables que se le indiquen
    en la lista que recibe como parámetro"""
    return (round(data[k],2) for k in variables)

def guardar():
    """Si se han introducido horas, hace los cálculos, extrae los resultados
    los guarda en la base de datos, y los muestra en la ventana de texto inferior"""

    crearTabla()  # No sé qué hace esta función, yo la he implementado vacía (no hace nada)

    if(hora_normal.get() == 0 and hora_extra.get()== 0):
        mostrarMensaje("Error", "Debes ingresar las horas laboradas ")
    else:
        calcular()
        variables_a_guardar = ["Cantidad H.N", "Cantidad H.E", "Total H. Semana", "Valor Semana",
                              "Total H.N", "Total H.E", "Total Año", "Diezmo Semana", "Diezmo Total",
                              "Dcto Semana", "Total Dcto", "Valor Total Año"]
        datos_a_guardar = extraer_valores_data(variables_a_guardar)
        insertar(datos_a_guardar)
        mostrarMensaje("Guardar", "Información Guardada")
        mostrar()

def mostrar():
    """Actualiza la ventana de texto inferior con los datos recuperados de la base de datos"""
    listado = consultar()
    textoBase.delete(1.0, END)
    textoBase.insert(INSERT, "Semana\tHoraN\tHoraE\tHSem\tValorS\tTotHN\tTotHE\tTotHAño\tDiezmoS\tDiezmoT\tDctoSem\tDctoTot\tValorTotalAño\n")
    for elemento in listado:
        textoBase.insert(INSERT, "\t".join(str(dato) for dato in elemento) + "\n")
    return

# Programa principal. Creación de la interfaz gráfica
ventana = Tk()
ventana.config(bg= colorVentana)
ventana.geometry(anchoAlto +posicionX + posicionY)
ventana. title("Calcula Sueldos")

# Creación de todas las etiquetas
Label(ventana, text ='"GOYA"', font=("Arial", 25)).place(x = 380, y = 10)
Label(ventana, text ='Alexander Carrero', width=15, height=2).grid(row = 4, column=0, padx=17, pady=20)

# Son muchas y todas se crean igual, así que lo hacemos con un bucle
messageLabel = {}
row = 8
column = 0
for fila in layout:
    column = 0
    for txt in fila:
        if txt == "Cantidad H.N":
            Label(ventana, text=txt, width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            hora_normal = DoubleVar()
            hora_normal_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_normal, width=11).grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        elif txt == "Cantidad H.E":
            Label(ventana, text ='Cantidad H. E', width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            hora_extra = DoubleVar()
            hora_extra_entrada = Entry(ventana, textvariable = hora_extra, width=11).grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        else:
            if txt == "Valor Total Año":
                column = 2  # este sigue otro patrón
            Label(ventana, text=txt, width=15).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=17, pady=10)
            messageLabel[txt] = Label(ventana, text='------------- ', width=11)
            messageLabel[txt].grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        column += 2
    row +=2


#Widgets
boton_calcular = Button(ventana, text= "Calcular Info", font=("Comic Sans", 13),  fg= "Blue", command = guardar, width= 15, height=2).place(x=160, y=350)
boton_salir = Button(ventana, text= "Limpiar Pantalla", font=("Comic Sans", 13),   fg= "Blue", command = limpiarDatos, width= 15, height=2).place(x=360, y=350)
boton_salir = Button(ventana, text= "Mostrar Info", font=("Comic Sans", 13),   fg= "Blue", command = mostrar, width= 15, height=2).place(x=560, y=350)
etiquetaBase = Label(ventana, text='"Histórico" ', font=("Arial", 25)).place(x = 380, y = 420)
textoBase = Text(ventana)
textoBase.config(width=120, height=35)
textoBase.place(x = 30, y = 470,)

# Arrancar interfaz
ventana.mainloop()
```

Esta es una captura de pantalla de una ejecución, tras haber metido datos (1h de cada tipo) tres veces:

[image: Resultado]

Como ves los totales se están calculando ahora correctamente. Además el código ha ganado en estructura y eficiencia (y es 76 líneas más corto a pesar de que introduje comentarios, lo que deja el listado en un 65% de lo que era, casi la mitad).

Una ventaja adicional es que ahora el código es mucho más **flexible**. Si quieres cambiar el *layout* (es decir, reorganizar el orden en que las diferentes variables se muestran en la interfaz), basta que edites la línea que define la variable `layout`. El código, al basarse en claves y no en posiciones concretas, seguirá funcionando, y el valor a mostrar "se moverá" automáticamente al lugar correcto.

Comment: definitivamente me falta mucho por aprender, tienes razón creo que me estaba complicando mucho con lo que estaba haciendo; agradezco enormemente tu orientación.